# Automapper setting property to null when it should ignore

Tags: c#, automapper

I was trying to implement a code to ignore a property (therefore mantaining the source value). I used the ignore method, which works most of the time. For some reason I noticed that sometimes the ignore sets the property value to null.

Do you know what could be problem?

I created the following code to reproduce the issue. I was expecting `client.ContactDetails.First().Address` to have the value "Old".

```
using AutoMapper;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ClientMapperProfile clientMapperProfile = new ClientMapperProfile();
        var configurationProvider = new MapperConfiguration(c => c.AddProfile(clientMapperProfile));
        Mapper mapper = new Mapper(configurationProvider);

        var client = new Client()
        {
            ContactDetails = new []
            {
                new ContactDetails()
                {
                    Address= "Old"
                }
            }
        };

        var clientDto = new ClientDto()
        {
            ContactDetails = new []
            {
                new ContactDetailsDto()
                {
                    Address = "New"
                }
            }
        };

        mapper.Map(clientDto,client);
        Console.WriteLine(client.ContactDetails.First().Address);
    }
}

public class Client
{
    public ContactDetails[] ContactDetails { get; set; }
}

public class ContactDetails
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

public class ClientDto
{
    public ContactDetailsDto[] ContactDetails { get; set; }
}

public class ContactDetailsDto
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

public class ClientMapperProfile : Profile
{
    public ClientMapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<ClientDto, Client>();

        CreateMap<ContactDetailsDto, ContactDetails>()
            .ForMember(c => c.Address, opt => opt.Ignore());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you think that it is the same instance ? Why you think that even `client.ContactDetails` is the same instance before and after ? add `var refClientContactDetails = client.ContactDetails;` before `mapper.Map(...)` and `Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(refClientContactDetails, client.ContactDetails));` after ... and everything  should be clear

Comment: I didn't get you comment @Selvin. The problem is that if, for instance, I create a `Address` property in `ClientDto` and `Client`, and then ignore the property in the mapping, when I perform the mapping this property will have the original value, not null.

Comment: Research AutoMapper.Collection.

Comment: Ok, I got the point, I need to define an equivalency criteria because othewise automapper doesn't know if it is the same object. Thanks